# Associating objects from multiple sources

Tags: java, spring

Lets suppose I have 2 classes:

```
EntityA {
    long id;
    EntityB entityB;
}

EntityB {
    long id;
}
```

EntityA is stored locally and EntityB is fetched remotely. I also have a service to fetch multiple EntitiesB at once:

```
List<EntityB> fetch (long... ids){/*...*/}
```

As I am not able to use relational joins I need some way to map the correct EntityB to EntityA efficiently, also trying to avoid parallel/async processing. My first approach will be using a HashMap indexed by EntityB key to avoid a NxN complexity search.

Before starting (and supposing I am not the first one with this problem) I would like to know: Is there any existing library that does something like that? Is there any approach more elegant/efficient?

Comment: What actually _**IS**_ the relationship between the two entities? Just from the pseudo-code, A _has-a_ B, so what is the relationship that decides which A gets which B? That is, how do you determine "the correct EntityB to EntityA"? It's hard to come up with a strategy without knowing.

Comment: The ids... A will have an idEntityB on local storage.